# How to find name of command in order to use the utility

Tags: command-line, package-management

There have been some instances where I installed a utility/program and the name of the command is different from the name of the program.

Like I installed PostgreSQL recently and after installation I ran the command

```
postgresql
```

but it gave an error `bash: postgresql command not found`

So I searched upon internet and found that the command to fire postgresql was

`psql`

So, how do I find out which utility/program to access with what name?

I did `apt-cache show postgresql` but even there it wasn't mentioned that the program would be accessed with the command `psql`

Please do not suggest `locate` command. It doesn't help.

Comment: Although I think this is a good question, I don't believe there's an answer to it. If I make an utility called `x` and call my executable `y` and I do not document it, there's no way of telling what the name of my executable is. This is a bad design choice on the side of the developers. Of course, you can install the package and look what new files you have on disk, but given that some packages install thousands of files, this procedure is not more straight forward than just googling for its name.

Comment: like many other programs, postgresql is something that you really ought to read the documentation for....if you don't know enough about to even know what the command-line client is called, how much do you really expect to be able to do with it?

Comment: @cas nobody knows anything until they start

Comment: @GypsyCosmonaut - yeah, that's why reading some documentation is generally a good idea.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One tactic would be to investigate what files the package installed into the various bin directories.  For instance, on a dpkg-based distribution, you might do something like:

```
dpkg -L postgresql-client-9.3 | grep bin
```

or on a system using RPMs you might do something like:

```
dnf repoquery -l PACKAGE_NAME | grep bin
```

and then read the manual pages for the binaries you find.  A challenges of this tactic is that in some cases (such as postgresql) the files are spread out over a few packages.

Comment: Package name in my kali (based on debian) repository is `postgresql` only so I did `dpkg -L postgresql | grep bin` but it did not list anything althought the package is located at `/usr/bin/psql`

Comment: @GypsyCosmonaut postgresql probably depends on a version-specific postgresql package which in turn depends on other packages.  Try `apt-cache depends postgresql` to see what that package depends on.

Comment: `apt-cache depends postgresql` gives me `Depends: postgresql-9.6` so I did `dpkg -L postgresql-9.6 | grep bin` this time and files from `/usr/lib/postgresql/9.6/bin` were listed in which there was no mention of `psql` because that file exists at `/usr/bin/psql` which was not listed in the result

Comment: Unfortunately, for the postgresql package, you would need to keep digging.  `psql` is shipped as part of the client package (likely: `postgresql-client-9.6`) which is a dependency of `postgresql-9.6`

Comment: this kind of task is part of the reason i wrote `dlocate` for debian (also because dpkg -L and dpkg -S were and still are slow).   e.g. `dlocate --lsbin postgresql-client-9.6` will show you all the binaries in that package.  `dlocate` also has `--lsman` and `--lsconf` and other options.

Answer (score 1):

**apropos** or **man -k**

This will do a search of installed manual pages related to your keyword. I would enter postgres as the keyword. On my system I get this:

```
$ apropos postgres
pam_postgresok (8)   - simple check of real UID and corresponding account name
pgsql_table (5)      - Postfix PostgreSQL client configuration
```