# how to find out what are the command of package?

Tags: kali-linux, packaging

i have package that install on my kali.

I want to find out what is Api of this package (what is all the function that i can write from terminal that this package will answer to me)

how can i get it from the terminal?

thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find name of command in order to use the utility](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/382821/how-to-find-name-of-command-in-order-to-use-the-utility)

Comment: `man -k package` might show you some relevant information, as well as the contents of `/usr/share/doc/package`.

Answer (score 2):

```
dpkg -L package
```

will list the contents of the (installed) `package`, and you can filter that to list files which end up on your path:

```
dpkg -L package | grep -E '/s?bin/|/games/'
```